# Is it possible to annotate method call in proto3

Tags: grpc

When `protoc` generating go file, I get a `FullMethod` - do you know if it is possible to annotate this on generation time or in proto3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `protoc` Golang file generation support both `proto2` and `proto3`. But currently the Golang plugin of `protoc` does not support gRPC method annotation.